# Adding a sequential letter to the end of a filename in Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a script to name a file with the user's username, date, then unique identifier. The objective is for a network of users to have a file name  generated for them in a standardized format in sequential order in a shared database. I am able to generate the username and date, but am having trouble assigning the identifier. I am thinking a sequential ascii_lowercase, but obviously I can not have a duplicate.

Examples: user doug saves 3 file edits on June 1, his files should be saved as `doug060115a`, `doug060115b`, `doug060115c`. user doug saves 1 more file edit on June 2, his file should now save as `doug060215a`.

So, the unique identifier at the end of the file name should start at a and if that is taken move on to b, then c, and so forth. If the username or date change the unique identifier should start over at a.

Comment: You are storing date anyway. Why don't store extra time? Like, seconds from `00:00`. It would make storing, naming and sorting these files simplier.

Comment: Character limit of 10 has the identifier reduced to 1 character. I have already had to shorten the username to the first 3 characters, the date is a standard 6 characters, which leaves 1 character.

Comment: If your character limit leaves only '1, maybe 2 digits', you will also have the unenviable task of mapping all user names into a 4 character space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an offset of the `ord` and some slicing

```
def incrementName(s):
    return s[:-1] + chr(ord(s[-1]) + 1)

>>> incrementName('doug060115b')
'doug060115c'
```

Not sure what you want to do once you hit `z` (if you anticipate that case)

Comment: This works.  The user still has the onerous task of find the *last* existing file in order to submit its name to 'incrementName()'.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing that in a table containing columns:

```
user_id, user, date, sequential_letter
```

If today the user adds more files you will check what letters are in use and assign the next one. If today's date changes you will start the sequence all over again. Sequential numbers will probably suit better for this purpose. You can use SQLite. Python handles it very well. http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/